# View distance as a function of elevation of observer

Tags: optics

I'm currently reading Jules Verne's Mysterious Island and the author, through his engineer character, keeps repeating the statement that if he climbs up to the top of a mountain to a height of **2500 ft** (762 m) - the highest peak on the island - he will be able to see about **50 miles** (80.5 km) through the horizon.

Is this a mathematical relationship between elevation and view distance (i.e. because of the curvature of the Earth) or is it merely a way of saying that he needs an unobstructed view and the 2500ft/50miles numbers are repeated for some other literary purpose?

Comment: A very rough computation leads to  $\simeq$120 Km. It is elementary Euclidean geometry of triangles. The the point at the maximal distance you can see is located where a straight line  exiting the top of the mountain touches the surface of Earth (it is tangent to the sphere there).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon Here there is a more precise computation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basic [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon) :

[image]

On the mountain of height $h$, one can see max (which is current distance $d$ to the horizon) :

$$ d=\sqrt {\left(R+h\right)^2-R^2} = \sqrt {2Rh+h^2} $$

Supplying book given data and Earth metrics (radius) :

$$ \sqrt{2×6~371~000 m × 762m + (762m)^2} $$

gives this seeing distance $\approx 60~\text{miles}$, which is off by author given answer by $10~miles$. But having in mind that we don't know what Earth radius author (or his references) has supplied into the formulas and exact calculation techniques at that time is also unknown,- this error margin should be acceptable.

**EDIT**

Provided that book script action goes on the island, it's very likely that author used distance is converted to Nautical miles. Hence when doing so we get $\approx 52~\text{Nautical Miles}$. Thus it matches given data in the book.

Comment: It's worth noting that unless the height of your mountain is a significant fraction of the radius of the Earth, you can approximate $\sqrt{2Rh + h^2} \approx \sqrt{2Rh}$ without a meaningful loss in accuracy.

Comment: Agree. $\sqrt{2Rh + h^2} = \sqrt{Rh(2 + h/R)}$ and when $h/R \ll 2$, then it boils down to $\sqrt{2Rh}$.